# Javascript html5 canvas random switch statement images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, switch-statement

I'm trying to randomly select a statement with values inside them which draws from a certain point in the sprite sheet. This is the current code I have.

```
    this.asteroid = Math.floor(Math.random()*7+1);
    switch(this.asteroid)
    {
    case 0:
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;
    case 1:
        this.srcX = 32;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;  
    case 2:
        this.srcX = 64;
        this.srcY = 528;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 33;
        break;
    case 3:
        this.srcX = 63;
        this.srcY = 565;
        this.width = 62;
        this.height = 60;           
        break;
    case 4:
        this.srcX = 125;
        this.srcY = 565;
        this.width = 62;
        this.height = 60;           
        break;
    case 5:
        this.srcX = 187;
        this.srcY = 565;
        this.width = 62;
        this.height = 60;           
        break;
    case 6:
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 632;
        this.width = 116;
        this.height = 120;          
        break;  
    }
```

I am then later on drawing the values it selects.

The problem I am having its drawing mostly all of them, but at the same time drawing just a blank image, I've checked all the X and Y locations and they are all correct and matching in the sprite sheet.

Below is the code I am using to draw my sprites:

```
this.drawX -= this.speed;
ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,
    this.srcX+this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.he‌​ight,
    this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
this.checkEscaped();
```

Comment: Can you put some example code into a jsFiddle, or at least add the code that performs the drawing operations to your question?

Comment: `this.drawX -= this.speed;`
 `ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX+this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);`
`this.checkEscaped();`

Is the code that draws it.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.floor(Math.random()*7+1)` can take values from 1 to 7. Remove the `+1`.

Comment: Without the +1 it only draws 5 out of 7 images.

Comment: Then you have other problems. If you want to explore all the branchs of your switch, including the first one, then the +1 is a bug.

Comment: @drystroy sorry what do you mean exactly?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*7+1)` **can't** give you 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem in your drawing code:

```
this.drawX -= this.speed;
ctxEnemy.drawImage(imgSprite,
    this.srcX+this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.he‌​ight,
    this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
this.checkEscaped();
```

In the line: `this.srcX+this.width,this.srcY,this.width,this.he‌​ight,`
You are adding the objects width to the source location. I think this might be throwing off your sprite drawing. See example with reference comment below:

```
// draw image to screen drawImage(imageObject, 
//     sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight,
//     destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight)
ctx.drawImage(imageObject, 
    this.srcX, this.srcY, this.width, this.height, 
    this.drawX, this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
```